# My progress bar colors are not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, css, html, firefox

So I have built out an interactive progress bar and everything works fine in Google Chrome and it even looks fine in Safari (surprisingly) without Safari vendor prefixes. However, the progress bar color goes back to the default blue color in Firefox. I've tried using vendor prefixes and it still changes back to blue. I'm kind of confused on what route I should take now. I have heard of but never used feature queries, not sure if this is an appropriate time to use them or what. The progress bar should be red until it gets to 100% then change to green. This is what I have so far:

```js
(function() {
  var button, heading, initialValue, progressbar;

  button = document.getElementById('btn');

  progressbar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');

  heading = document.getElementById('visual-progress');

  initialValue = 'Quiz Progress';

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var myValue;
    if (progressbar.value >= 100) {
      progressbar.value = 100;
    } else {
      progressbar.value += 25;
    }
    if (progressbar.value === 100) {
      progressbar.classList.add('progress-100');
    }
    myValue = initialValue + ' ' + progressbar.value;
    document.getElementById('visual-progress').innerHTML = myValue + '%';
    return button.classList.add('button-active');
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display");
nav {
  background: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.progress-container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #D22128 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

progress::-moz-progress-value {
  background-color: #D22128 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

.progress-100::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: forestgreen !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.progress-100::-moz-progress-value {
  background-color: forestgreen !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .7em 3em;
}

.button-active {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.card-container {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.success-message {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  -webkit-animation: slideUp .5s;
          animation: slideUp .5s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 3em;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.success-paragraph {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='progress-container'>
      <h1 class='ut-margin-v-sm' id='visual-progress'>Quiz Progress</h1>
      <progress id='progress-bar' max='100' value='0'></progress>
      <button id='btn'>Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card-container'>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: To emphasize what @Kaiido says in an answer, `::-webkit-progress-value` is non-standard and not in any standards specification. Therefore, there is no such thing as `::-moz-progress-value`.

Comment: @Rob if I'm not mistaken, neither is `::[-XXX-]progress-bar`.

Comment: @Kaiido It is available but, again, it's non-standard and shouldn't be used: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-progress-bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firefox doesn't seem to have the [::progress-value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-progress-value) pseudo-element implemented.

For this browser, you will directly target the parent [::progress-bar](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-moz-progress-bar).

```js
(function() {
  var button, heading, initialValue, progressbar;

  button = document.getElementById('btn');

  progressbar = document.getElementById('progress-bar');

  heading = document.getElementById('visual-progress');

  initialValue = 'Quiz Progress';

  button.addEventListener('click', function() {
    var myValue;
    if (progressbar.value >= 100) {
      progressbar.value = 100;
    } else {
      progressbar.value += 25;
    }
    if (progressbar.value === 100) {
      progressbar.classList.add('progress-100');
    }
    myValue = initialValue + ' ' + progressbar.value;
    document.getElementById('visual-progress').innerHTML = myValue + '%';
    return button.classList.add('button-active');
  });

}).call(this);
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Playfair+Display");
nav {
  background: black;
  height: 80px;
  width: 100%;
}

.container {
  max-width: 800px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 10px;
}

.progress-container {
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin-top: 3em;
}

progress {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress{ /* for FF target directly the element */
  background-color: #ccc;
  width: 100%;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: #D22128 !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .7s;
  transition: all .7s;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar { /* for FF ::progress-bar is the value bar */
  background-color: #D22128 !important;
  transition: all .7s;
}

.progress-100::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: forestgreen !important;
  -webkit-transition: all .5s;
  transition: all .5s;
}

.progress-100::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: forestgreen !important;
  transition: all .5s;
}

button {
  margin-top: 2em;
  background: transparent;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid black;
  padding: .7em 3em;
}

.button-active {
  -webkit-transition: all .2s;
  transition: all .2s;
  background: black;
  color: white;
}

.card-container {
  max-width: 450px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.success-message {
  font-family: 'Playfair Display', serif;
  text-align: center;
  padding-bottom: 2em;
  -webkit-animation: slideUp .5s;
          animation: slideUp .5s;
  box-shadow: 0 10px 28px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), 0 6px 13px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.22);
  padding: 20px;
  margin-top: 3em;
  min-height: 150px;
}

.success-paragraph {
  font-size: 14px;
}

@-webkit-keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}

@keyframes slideUp {
  from {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(500px);
            transform: translateY(500px);
  }
  to {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
            transform: translateY(0);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <nav></nav>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='progress-container'>
      <h1 class='ut-margin-v-sm' id='visual-progress'>Quiz Progress</h1>
      <progress id='progress-bar' max='100' value='0'></progress>
      <button id='btn'>Next</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class='card-container'>
    <div id='output'></div>
  </div>
</body>
```